# Scripts timeout using USBMount

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, udev

I'm using Usbmount (https://github.com/rbrito/usbmount) on a raspbian system to auto-detect the insertion and removal of a usb stick in to the unit and then run a script from the /etc/usbmount/mount.d/ folder accordingly.

The scripts run fine, but the problem is the scripts stop in the middle of copy operations when run using Usbmount. If run from the command line they work just fine.

It appears to be a udevd timeout problem. The syslog says:

```
usbmount[835]: executing command: run-parts /etc/usbmount/mount.d
systemd-udevd[802]: timeout: killing '/usr/share/usbmount/usbmount add'   [835]
systemd-udevd[802]: '/usr/share/usbmount/usbmount add' [835] terminated by signal 9 (Killed)
```

My usbmount.conf is set to the default. USB stick is FAT32.

What's the best way to get around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue using the at command. The at tools can schedule tasks to run at given time, in our case we'll use the "now" time to run it immediately.

If you don't have the at command installed, you have to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install at
```

Then create a text file with a list of commands you want to run without timeout  separated by new lines, and name it whatever you want, let's say "command".
Then add this line to you usbmount script:

```
at -f command now
```

It should avoid the timeout this way.

Comment: Confirmed. That's how we did it too, in the end.