# Timing out in scripts with usbmount

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, udev

I have created a script that would do certain tasks that will take quite a while. The script is ran when a device is mounted with `usbmount` but it turns out there is a timeout limit.

```
systemd-udevd: timeout: killing '/usr/share/usbmount/usbmount add'  
systemd-udevd: '/usr/share/usbmount/usbmount add' terminated by signal 9 (Killed)
```

There is a [similar question that I found](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/265780/scripts-timeout-using-usbmount) which suggests using `at`. However, with that I couldn't figure out how I can pass the `${UM_MOUNTPOINT}` variable to my script. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that `at` accepts commands from `stdin`, so I piped my command with the arguments to it:

```
echo "command '${UM_MOUNTPOINT}'" | at now
```

This solved the problem.